# Определить состояние человека в группе ВК на стороне сервера php

Tags: php, javascript, вконтакте

Ищу способ, что бы можно было определить состоит ли мой пользователь сайта в моей офф. группе этого сайта. Возможно ли это вообще средствами PHP или Javascript?

Comment: Состояние - это не совсем то, что имелось в виду. Интересующая вас информация называется членством. Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уже не актуально, возвращает

```
 {
  "error": {
    "error_code": 8,
    "error_msg": "Invalid request: v (version) is required",
    "request_params": [{
      "key": "oauth",
      "value": "1"
    }, {
      "key": "method",
      "value": "groups.isMember"
    }, {
      "key": "group_id",
      "value": "165323728"
    }, {
      "key": "user_id",
      "value": "28900072"
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: Извеняюсь, а что не актуально?

Answer (score 1):

У ВКонтакте есть API. В API есть метод [groups.isMember](https://vk.com/dev/groups.isMember), который делает ровно то, что вам нужно.

К тому же он открытый — не нужно регистрировать приложение, просто дергаете url с нужными параметрами.

```
//Состоит ли пользователь с id = 1 в группе с id = 1
https://api.vk.com/method/groups.isMember?group_id=1&user_id=1
```

Comment: Окей, а как узнать user_id, без участия пользователя?

Comment: @igolka97 https://vk.com/dev/openapi см. «Пример авторизации через Open API»

Comment: @igolka97 я думаю без участия пользователя никак, это было-бы нарушением конфиденциальности.